# Cannot Navigate to Nested/Child Route using parent named router outlet

Tags: angular

I previously used ui-router in AngularJS then Angular 2+. I would like to move to the @angular/router simply because it seems to be more supported and more libraries built on it (ui-router-ng2 is still in beta!!)

My problem is that I am using a main template that has named route outlets because the main template has a static header and footer that is reused. (there is also a sidebar which i took out for brevity)

My problem is that once I get into my '/mainDashboard' router I am having trouble navigating from that route into the next nested/child route '/otherDashboard' whilst trying to use the named router outlet in the main template 'content'

How should I be navigating to my route in the thirteenth line of my code below.
There is also a [plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/RErIiby535x0toaA02W4?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/RErIiby535x0toaA02W4?p=preview)

Here is my code

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: '<button (click)="go()">Go To Other Dashboard</button>'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor( public router: Router ) {}
  go(){ 
    //THIS ERRORS
    this.router.navigate(['../dashboard',{outlets: {'content': ['../dashboard/mainDashboard/otherDashboard']}}]);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-dashboard',
  template: `
    <header>My Static Header</header>
    <div id="main-container" class="main-background">
        <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <footer>My Static Footer</footer>
  `
})
export class MainDashboardComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

@Component({selector: 'app-login',template: '<button (click)="login()">Login</button>'})
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router) { };
    login(){
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard',{outlets: {content: ['mainDashboard']}}]);
    }
}

@Component({selector: 'app-other-dashboard', template: '<h1>Hello Other Dashboard</h1>'})
export class OtherDashboardComponent{
  constructor() { }
}

export const routes: Array<any> = [
    {path: '',component: LoginComponent },
    {path: 'dashboard', component: MainDashboardComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'mainDashboard',component: HomeComponent,outlet: 'content',
                children: [{path: 'otherDashboard',component: OtherDashboardComponent,  outlet: 'content'}]
            }
        ]
    }
]

    @Component({ selector: 'app-root', template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'})
    export class AppComponent {}

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent, LoginComponent, MainDashboardComponent, HomeComponent, OtherDashboardComponent],
      imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing with your plunker code I found out the issue. As your `otherDashboard` is child of `mainDashboard` it is expected to have the router outlet for `otherDashboard` inside `mainDashboard`. Once that is added I was able to navigate to `otherDashboard` using `router.navigateByUrl` So your `HomeComponent` will look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: '<button (click)="go()">Go To Other Dashboard</button><router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor( public router: Router ) {}
  go(){ 
    //Error gone
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard/(content:mainDashboard/(content:otherDashboard))');
  }
}
```

If you want to replace the `HomeComponent` with `OtherDashboardComponent` in `MainDashboardComponent` itself then in both `otherDashboard` and `mainDashboard` should be children of same parent that is `HomeComponent`

Working code: https://plnkr.co/edit/jYOMNhbE3lX5UYmjS7qy?p=preview

Comment: This kind of solution is awful, this doesnt solve anything. You are just entering the exact url to the router. This isn't abstract and cant be used in any other case. You will have to change the Url here everytime you decide to change your paths...